# Azure VM - can't connect after ipconfig /release

Tags: virtual-machines, remote-desktop, azure, ipconfig

I was having some intermittent trouble connecting from my Azure VM to an on premise SQL Server instance and, without really thinking about the consequences, I ran `ipconfig /release`..

Now I can't connect via remote desktop connection.  I've tried using the Azure Portal to resize the VM but the operation fails.  I've got a remote PowerShell connection to the VM but when I run the `ipconfig /renew` command I get an error:

```
Windows IP Configuration

An error occurred while renewing interface Ethernet 3 : unable to contact your DHCP server. Request has timed out.
```

Is there anything I can do to restore connectivity or do I need to delete and re-create the virtual machine?

Comment: I'd just contact Azure support.

Comment: Restarting it should allocate it a new IP